# Why are these two types different?

Tags: java

I split String to String[] arr and want to compare element of arr with String
but I don't know why System.out.println(arr[0] == "P"); return 'false'

Please check my code and answer to me. Thank you!

```
enter code here
String s = "pPooyy";
s = s.toUpperCase(); 
String[] arr; 
arr = s.split("");

System.out.println(arr[0]);
System.out.println(arr[0] == "P");
```

this is result.
P
false

System.out.println(arr[0]); -> the result of this println is P so I thought System.out.println(arr[0] == "P"); would return 'true' but it wasn't.

Why  are these two types different?

Comment: *"I simply want to know why does this statement, `System.out.println(arr[0] == "P")` print false"* - Because `arr[0]` and `"P"` are not the same object.  That is what `==` means for reference values.   The correct way to test if two strings are equal (in the intuitive sense) is described in the dup-linked Q&A.

Comment: *"Why are these two types different?"* - The types are not different.  It is the values that are different.  Types and values are not the same thing.

Comment: @Stephen C Thank you so much for you answel! based on your answel, I could find the difference between '==' with .equals() and also I figure I need to learn about CBR, CBV!

Comment: I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use charAt ?

```
Syso(s.charAt(0)=='P')
```

Let me know if this helps

Comment: Thank you for  your answer! but I simply want to know why does this statement, System.out.println(arr[0] == "P"); return false..